# Why program broken with an error exc_bad_access code=exc_i386_gpflt

Tags: c++, algorithm

I don't understand, why my program broken with an error `exc_bad_access code=exc_i386_gpflt` in this line `matrix[row].push_back(cell);`?

So, my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int calculate(int cell_1x1_price, int cell_1x2_price) {
  if ((cell_1x1_price + cell_1x1_price) < cell_1x2_price) {
    return cell_1x1_price + cell_1x1_price;
  } else {
    return cell_1x2_price;
  }
}

int main() {

  using std::cin;
  using std::cout;
  using std::string;
  using std::vector;

  int rows;
  int columns;
  int cell_1x2_price;
  int cell_1x1_price;

  cin >> rows >> columns >> cell_1x2_price >> cell_1x1_price;

  vector<string> matrix;
  matrix.reserve(rows);

  char cell;

  for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
    for (int column = 0; column < columns; ++column) {
      cin >> cell;
      matrix[row].push_back(cell);
    }
  }

  int sum = 0;

  for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
    for (int column = 0; column < columns; ++column) {
      if (matrix[row][column] == '*') {
        if (column + 1 < columns && matrix[row][column + 1] == '*') {
          sum += calculate(cell_1x1_price, cell_1x2_price);
          ++column;
          continue;
        }
        if (row + 1 < rows && matrix[row + 1][column] == '*') {
          matrix[row + 1][column] = '.';
          sum += calculate(cell_1x1_price, cell_1x2_price);
          continue;
        }

        sum += cell_1x1_price;
      }
    }
  }

  cout << sum;

  return 0;
}
```

About what do program and inputs: First string includes 4 integers: N, M, A, B (1 ≤ N, M ≤ 300, A, B ≤ 1000). Each next line include M-symbols. Symbol . is a clean cell, * and ** are dirty.

I need to find the sum for cleaning if A its sum of ** cell, B is sum of *.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you call matrix[row] when matrix is in fact an empty vector.

The call to matrix.reserve(rows) only increases vector's capacity, it does not add any elements to it. You can use matrix.resize(rows) for this, or just pass the size to the vector's constructor, like

```
vector<string> matrix(rows);
```